# UsedRange lastrow computing extra rows

Tags: excel, vba

This code is supposed to make a formula go from C9 until the last row used in C. I am using UsedRange because from C1 to C9, there are empty values.

```
lastrow = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

ws1.Range("C9:C" & lastrow).Formula = _
    "=INDEX(Tableau_Employés[EMPLOYÉ],MATCH('Overtime KRONOS'!$A9,Tableau_Employés[ORDRE D''ANCIENNETÉ]))"
```

However this pastes the formula too far, going 11 rows after the last row. I'm not sure why.

Comment: `UsedRange` has issues. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).

Comment: try lastrow = ws1.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: @Blade Daniel `rows.count` future proofs it: `lastrow = ws1.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 0):

Changed to

`lastrow = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`